# acme.sh script to include the webmail subdomain on a shared (Namecheap) server

Tags: linux, ssl, lets-encrypt

For a long time I have used acme.sh to create 90-day SSL certs for my example.com domain. Never had a problem.

However, I now wish to start using the webmail interface (webmail.example.com - included with hosting), but the usual acme.sh script fails.

This works:

```
./acme.sh --issue -d example.com -d www.example.com -w /home/myuserid/public_html
```

This fails:

```
./acme.sh --issue -d example.com -d www.example.com -d webmail.example.com -w /home/myuserid/public_html
```

What must I do to fix this?  My webhost is Namecheap.

Answer (score 0):

I think the webmail subdomain might be using a different document root for serving files. You need to find the correct document root for your webmail subdomain, and specify it in the acme.sh command.

Here what you can do, log in to your cPanel on NameCheap, go to Subdomains, then find the webmail.example.com subdomain, and check its document root. It might be something like /home/myuserid/public_html/webmail/

then use this command accordingly with the correct document root `./acme.sh --issue -d example.com -d www.example.com -d webmail.example.com -w /home/myuserid/public_html -w /home/myuserid/public_html -w /home/myuserid/public_html/webmail/`

now, run `acme.sh` and it should work.